# Border radius applied to td has no inner radius

Tags: css

When I apply a border and border radius to a td, the inner radius is a right angle and not rounded at all.

[image]

Comment: What's inside your `<td>`? Try applying the radius to that...

Comment: I cant. I have limited control over the markup, I cant add spans or divs.

Comment: I'm not saying add anything to the markup... There might be a text box or something inside the `td` - the sharp corner you're seeing there could be the outside border of whatever's in there.

Comment: did you succeed with your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is a child element with opaque background which will clip the inner radius of the border.

To fix this you can apply `overflow:hidden` on your `td` .

You can play with the overflow in [this Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfYqP/3/) to see the effect.